# Recover Xcode Project from Archive?

Tags: xcode, file, archive, recover

I don't know how but I deleted my .Xcodeproj and everything associated with it. I really don't know how, but its on the app store, and I still have the archive for it. Is there any way to retrieve it? I know its not strictly about programming, but is there any way to recover my project from the archive that I have currently?

Any tips or programs that anyone recommends would be appreciated greatly!

Comment: Time Machine? Did you keep any backups? Disk recovery software? Aside from that, you're probably out of luck. (Not an answer because it's not an answer.)

Comment: Nope, thats kind of why i'm in a panic.

Comment: Nope, anything relevant is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may go through the following link

http://mackeeper.zeobit.com/mac-undelete

You can also try TimeMachine backup, if you use it, to retrieve it.

hope it helps you!!!

Comment: well it didn't really work, but I appreciate the help considering nobody else did.